# How to build a particular version of gcc (4.5.1)?

Tags: gcc, downgrade

In my office we have **gcc-4.5.1**, with that version my c++ project works fine. 
If I compile the same project at home with Ubuntu 12.04 with **gcc-4.6**, I have lot of errors and I couldn't compile at all. I spent some time on the Internet to build the gcc from sources but the installation had lot of issues and the build is broken.

I am looking for a way to downgrade my gcc version to **4.5.1**.

If someone can also give a step by step way of compiling gcc from sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the gcc-4.5-base package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5-base
```

You might need to install a specific version of that package. Check the [package change log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gcc-4.5/gcc-4.5_4.5.3-12ubuntu2/changelog).

To install the last 4.5.1 update try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5-base=4.5.1-12
```

(note that 4.5.1-12 was marked as experimental in the change log. This is just an example!)

For more info on installing old versions of packages with apt take a look at:

http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html